# How to save inputted txt file to variable bash

Tags: bash

I want to prompt the user to type in a text file then save that text file as a variable so I can manipulate it further within the rest of my shell script.  (For instance, save it to a different filename, edit the data inside, etc).

Unfortunately I don't have a good starting point as everything I've tried so far has failed.

Comment: `echo "What is your name" ; read name ; echo "Hello $name, welcome to tomorrow"`. Good luck.

Comment: It would be more helpful to say what's "everything I've tried". There are only a certain number of things that you could try, and it's hard to imagine reading user input being so hard.

Comment: Also, it's usually bad practice to read filename interactively, unless you have a valid reason to do so. Use command line arguments.

Comment: There's a great introduction to bash [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), you'll probably want to start on the [Catching user input](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read -p "what file name you want to use" filename

echo ${filename} #or whatever you want to do with filename variable
```